# Change to Xaml code not reflected in Design View in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 PC

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I am taking an online tutorial (Lynda.com, "Creating a Windows Store App with Visual Studio 2012").

The tutorial shows that changing the XAML code from this:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
```

To this:

```
<Grid Background="Orange">
```

Changes the background to orange in the IDE.  This makes sense.  It's easy. It works in the tutorial, but not for me.  When I run the program (a hello world program without the hello world), the screen color is the default of blue.  Other changes in the XAML code don't find there way into the design view or the runtime view. Weird. Something is wrong somewhere.  What could be wrong?

Comment: More information.  Lynda.com provides all of the source code for the sample programs in their tutorials.  I opened many of them in Visual Studio 2013, update 3, and built them.  At runtime they ran, but presented nothing but a blue screen.  The settings charm, however, showed the name of the program and the name of the program author.  I do have the required Microsoft Windows 8 developer license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's tecnnical support solved this problem for me with an assist from the Dell Computer Corporation.

The problem was caused because an older version of a device driver for an Intel(R) HD graphics card was on my PC.  Acquiring and installing the latest version of the device driver solved the problem.